# jQuery is only returning first item

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For some strange reason, whenever I have a selector and expect to get multiple items, jQuery is only returning the first item, instead of the entire collection.

This is the HTML I have:

```
<a id="reply-424880" class="reply" href="#" rel="nofollow">Reply</a>
<a id="reply-424885" class="reply" href="#" rel="nofollow">Reply</a>
```

And the selector:

```
$('.reply').unbind('click').click(function(event) {
 ...
}
```

I have tried debugging using FireBug, and still get the same results. Using the work around I can get it to work:

```
$('a').each(function (index, element) {
            if ($(element).attr('class') == 'reply') {
                $(this).unbind('click').click(function(event) {
                     ...
                });
             }
});
```

I would like to use the built-in functionality instead of my work around.  Any idea why only the first element would be returned?

Comment: Does `console.log( $('.reply') )` really return only one element?

Comment: Are you sure that is the problem (it is only returning one item)? What does $('.reply').length return?

Comment: In this page, I have 51 links on the page and 7 links w/ a class "reply". 
$('.reply').length; returns "1", 
and $('a').length; return "51"

I have this problem on 2 other pages that are not related to "replies".  It is possible that something on my page is preventing the selector from working, but don't know what to look into.

Comment: Other responders are right, your example is correct. You may want to provide complete page for testing. Or remove some content from it, but please make sure it still fails your test. So far, there is no error to discuss.

Comment: Btw instead of using `if ($(element).attr('class') == 'reply')`  use ` if ($(element).hasClass("reply")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After leaving the workaround in place for a couple of months, I decided to try to see if there was anything on the page that was causing the problem.

By process of elimination, I was able to narrow down the error to the jquery.validate.js file.  For some unknown reason, this file was causing the jQuery to only return the first value.  I downloaded the latest version and the selectors now return *all* the elements that match.

Answer (score 30):

Awkwardly, I also had this problem and it turned out to be that Chrome appears to have a $() jquery-like function that implements a subset of selector logic in a similar fashion, but missing a bunch of functions:

```
> $
function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

Vs with jQuery correctly included:

```
> $
function (e,n){return new x.fn.init(e,n,t)}
```

So.. yeah, turns out I'd slightly malformed my script tag - not enough to cause any errors, and it still fetched the jQuery file so the network view still showed it being fetched, it just wasn't then being interpreted as javascript, and as such jQuery was missing, but enough of the syntax still worked that it threw me for ages.

Hopefully this saves someone some time at some point.

Comment: Incidentally, Chrome also has a `$$` function which returns an array of elements matching the selector.  More info [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#selector_1).

Comment: @Jthorpe this is absolutely awesome, maybe wort to make a own question regarding chrome and answering it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Whyever did they choose '$' for this?

Answer (score 3):

What you have should be working already, [you can see an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/eqYTC/), this is a simple call:

```
$('.reply').unbind('click').click(function(event) {
  alert('hi there');
});​
```

You must have something outside the question affecting your links if the same handler's not being executed for all of them.  If you're getting an [*attribute*](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) from the first only, make sure inside your function you're not doing something like `$(".reply").attr("id")`, you should be using `this` inside the handler, of you'll get the attribute from the first element matched.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/eqYTC/1/):

```
$('.reply').unbind('click').click(function(event) {
  alert($('.reply').attr("id")); //alerts "reply-424880" for both
});​
```

[It should be like this](http://jsfiddle.net/eqYTC/2/):

```
$('.reply').unbind('click').click(function(event) {
  alert($(this).attr("id")); //alerts "reply-424880" for both
  //and use just this.id in this case, no need for jQuery .attr(), like this
  //alert(this.id);
});​
```

Comment: Yea I don't see where they could be going wrong... Definitely a simple call. +1

Answer (score 0):

That should work but what about ...

```
$('.reply').each(function() { 
   $(this).unbind('click').click(function(event) {
      ... 
   });
});
```

Comment: this is not the problem,